# How to Animate closing dropdown menu with js and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, css-animations

I have a menu with submenu items, i managed to create a simple animation with css keyframe when opening dropdown, but i can't do the same when dropdown is closed. How can I add animation when the dropdown is closed ? As you can see, when you close the dropdown there is no transition, it just disappears instantly.

Old Snippet

```js
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-btn');
//Add this for toggling dropdown
lastOpened = null;

dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var menuContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  menuContent.classList.toggle("show"); 
  
  //Add this for toggling dropdown
  if (lastOpened && lastOpened !== menuContent)
      lastOpened.classList.remove("show");
      lastOpened = menuContent;
}));
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.menu-btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}


.drop_container {
   display: none;
   background-color: #017575;
   animation:animateFromBottom .3s;
}

.drop_container.show {
  display: block;
  
}

.drop_container > .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

@keyframes animateFromBottom {
    from{bottom:-50px;opacity:0} 
    to{bottom:0;opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animateToBottom {
  from{bottom:0;opacity:1} 
  to{bottom:-50px;opacity:0}
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">

<div class="menu-btn">One</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
</div>

<div class="menu-btn">Two</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
</div>

</div>
```

**Edit Snippet**: I decided not to use css keyframe, just transition with max-height. This makes it easier for me to make changes, I'm still just a beginner and just stick to the simple stuff. However, when you switch between items it is still not playing any animation. I see that @EmielZuurbier's solution adds animation even when switching from one item to another, how can I make this to my modified code ?

```js
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-btn');
//Add this for toggling dropdown
lastOpened = null;

dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var menuContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (!menuContent.classList.contains("show")) {
  menuContent.classList.add("show");
  menuContent.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
  menuContent.classList.add("hide");
  menuContent.classList.remove("show");
  }
  
  //Add this for toggling dropdown
  if (lastOpened && lastOpened !== menuContent)
      lastOpened.classList.remove("show");
      lastOpened = menuContent;
}));
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.menu-btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0; 
}

.drop_container.show {
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
}

.drop_container.hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
}

.drop_container > .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">

<div class="menu-btn">One</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
</div>

<div class="menu-btn">Two</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: N.B. You can use the `classList.toggle('my-class')` method. This removes the class if it is present and adds it if it is absent. Consequently, this: `if (!menuContent.classList.contains("show")) {menuContent.classList.add("show"); menuContent.classList.remove("hide");} else {menuContent.classList.add("hide"); menuContent.classList.remove("show");}` becomes two short statements without a need for conditional logic: `menuContent.classList.toggle("hide"); menuContent.classList.toggle("show");`

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine Thanks for the suggestion, I appreciate it. I have already tried it, in fact it was the initial idea, but then I did not understand why the menu does not work as it should. with classList.toggle I end up with this: `div class="drop_container hide show"` so the main class acquires both hide and show.

Comment: It's only because you need to initialise `.drop-container` with `.hide`. Your initial markup should read: `<div class="drop_container hide">`.

Comment: I'm trying but it doesn't seem to work, if you like could you answer me with an example? I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an example below, using CSS Transitions and CSS Custom Properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. Because you're showing and hiding the drop down lists with the `display` property we'll need to stick to animations.

Create a new class for the `animateToBottom` keyframes. This class should be added *after* an element with the `show` class should animate out.

Only after the "out" animation has finished should the `show` class be removed. With the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event we can see when our animation finishes so we can hide the dropdown.

```js
const dropdownBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-btn');
let lastOpened = null;

dropdownBtns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const menuContent = this.nextElementSibling;

  if (lastOpened !== null) {
    const target = lastOpened;
 
    target.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
      target.classList.remove('show', 'animate-out');
 
      if (target === lastOpened) {
        lastOpened = null;
      }
    }, {
      once: true
    });

    target.classList.add('animate-out');
  }

  if (lastOpened !== menuContent) {
    menuContent.classList.add('show');
    lastOpened = menuContent;
  }
}));
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.menu-btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop_container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #017575;
  animation: animateFromBottom .3s;
}

.drop_container.show {
  display: block;
}

.drop_container.show.animate-out {
  animation: animateToBottom .3s;
}

.drop_container>.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

@keyframes animateFromBottom {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animateToBottom {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">

  <div class="menu-btn">One</div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-btn">Two</div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different solution which involves **CSS Transitions** and **CSS Custom Properties**.

With this approach the accordion menu sections are initially set to `.hide`.

The sections are then toggled (using `.classList.toggle()`) between `.hide` and `.show`.

- a class of `.hide` means the `height` is `0`
- a class of `.show` means the `height` is `var(--openHeight)`

The `height` will animate between these two values.

The `var(--openHeight)` is calculated individually for *each* `menuItemData` - it is equivalent to `menuItemData.scrollHeight`.

Via this technique we can enable a smooth CSS transition between `0` and a value which CSS cannot guess at, but JavaScript can readily tell us.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
let dropdownMenuItemTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu-item-title');

dropdownMenuItemTitles.forEach(menuItemTitle => {
  menuItemTitle.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    const menuItemData = e.target.nextElementSibling;

    menuItemData.style.setProperty('--openHeight', menuItemData.scrollHeight + 'px');

    menuItemData.classList.toggle('show');
    menuItemData.classList.toggle('hide');
  })
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu-item-title {
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu-item-title:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu-item-data {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.3s ease-out;
}

.dropdown-menu-item-data.hide {
  height: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu-item-data.show {
  height: var(--openHeight);
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu-item {
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="dropdown-menu">
  <div>
    <dt class="dropdown-menu-item-title">One</dt>
    <dd class="dropdown-menu-item-data hide">
      <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#">Visit Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <dt class="dropdown-menu-item-title">Two</dt>
    <dd class="dropdown-menu-item-data hide">
      <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#">Visit Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#">Opening Times</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </div>

  <div>
    <dt class="dropdown-menu-item-title">Three</dt>
    <dd class="dropdown-menu-item-data hide">
      <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#">Visit Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </div>
</dl>

</div>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties